# Need to merge address book files

Tags: contacts

Can I import an old Address Book file without replacing my current contacts? In other words, can I merge an old address book file with my current one?

I use address book on OS X 10.10.1 and iOS 8.1.3 so whichever can assist can be used.

Comment: I'm going to place a hold on this to get some details edited into the post. Do you use OS X or iOS or both? What versions? Do your contacts cloud sync to one or more services? The answers depend on this level of detail.

Comment: Both. 10.10.1 & 8.1.3

Comment: Ok. If you can edit in if you sync via iCloud that might help, but let's see what answers arrive...

Comment: Define "address book file" please...  It is a backup?  is it a collection of vcards?  How did you create it, and with what version of OS X?